# How to save a belongs_to association for a polymorphic model with nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

For example I have these models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: id, name
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: id, name, main_address_id
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
  belongs_to :main_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: :main_address_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :main_address

  def main_address_attributes=(attributes)
    puts '='*100
    puts attributes.inspect
    self.build_main_address(attributes)
    self.main_address.addressable_id = self.id
    self.main_address.addressable_type = self.class.to_s
    puts self.inspect
    puts self.main_address.inspect
  end
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes: id, address1, address2, city_id,..
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
  validates :addressable_id, :addressable_type, presence: true
end
```

I am trying to save the `Company` with nested attributes, you can assume this as the params:

```
{"name"=>"Test Company", "email"=>"", "display_name"=>"Company pvt ltd", "description"=>"Company desc", "founded_in"=>"2014-08-05", "website"=>"", "main_address_attributes"=>{"address1"=>"My address1", "address2"=>"My address2", "city_id"=>"10"}}
```

This doesn't work as it rejects and doesn't save data when addressable(`addressable_id` and `addressable_type`) for **main_address** isn't present, even when I am trying to add it in `main_address_attributes=(attributes)` method in `Company` class.

Whenever I try to save this with the above params I get this error:

```
Main address addressable can't be blank
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: do you want to save `company` which is related to `address` (through `main_address_id`) which in return is related to something else(`Company` or `Person`) through `addressable`??

Comment: No, `Company` has two separate addresses, one is main address and another is optional address, a `Person` can have an address but it is off the topic. What I need is the way to save main_address_id as created `Address` id with addressable pointing to the created `Company`. I hope that helps.

Comment: in this case you should use the same `polymorphic` relation (otherwise you will have something about what I have written above)

Comment: it's not answer on your question, but looks like you should `has_one :address, as: :addressable` change to `has_many :address, as: :addressable`, and then add `enum type: [:primary, :secondary]` to your `Address`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will look for more options, if I can't find any I'll accept your answer. So, put your suggestion in an answer. Also, note that you can't have `enum` as `type` because column is reserved for single-table-inheritance. it can be address_type or something. Thank you anyways. :)

Comment: `type` fields it's common mistake;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case with `belongs_to` you will have something like: `company` related to `address` (through `main_address_id`) which in return is related to another(`Company` or `Person`) through polymorphic `addressable`.

As example you could change:

```
has_one :address, as: :addressable
```

to:

```
has_many :address, as: :addressable
```

and then add to your `Address`:

```
enum address_type: [:primary, :secondary]
```